# How to select some data from DataTable

Tags: asp.net

I want to search some data from DataTable to show in GridView.

Like

```
(select * from customer where id="1")
```

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataRow[] foundRows = yourTable.Select("id=1");
```

Or you can filter rows in default view:

```
yourTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "id = 1";
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSourse = yourTable.DefaultView
gv.DataBind()
```